# sql: left join multitables with the on the same key

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Given the three following tables:

table1

```
id   name      observation
--------------------------
1    mario     serial
2    samantha  drogue dealer
3    jennifer  prostitute
4    megan     nun
```

table 2

```
id   person_id  contact
-------------------------
1    2          jefferson
```

table 3

```
id   person_id salary
---------------------
1     2        180 000
2     4        0
```

I want the output to be

```
id   name      observation    contact     salary
-------------------------------------------------
1    mario     serial          NULL       NULL
2    samantha  drogue dealer   jefferson  180 000
3    jennifer  prostitute      NULL       NULL
4    megan     nun             NULL       0
```

Should I use left join multiple times in here?
How to do this?

Comment: Your database contains some real bad guys! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary table is your Table1.  The secondary are both for contact and salary.  By doing a LEFT-JOIN from your main to the secondary means give me the record on the left regardless of the match found on the right.  The join is based on the secondary table's "person_id"

```
select
      t1.id,
      t1.name,
      t1.observation,
      t2.contact,
      t3.salary
   from
      table1 t1
         LEFT JOIN table2 t2
            on t1.id = t2.person_id
         LEFT JOIN table3 t3
            on t1.id = t3.person_id
```